# Basic Z-score probability estimation when z-score is positive versus when z-score is negative

Tags: probability, z-score

I am trying to estimate the probability of a value being less than 75.

I have two means (two different groups). The mean of the first group (76,06) gives me a negative z-score  (-1,47), and the mean of the second group (74,51) gives me a positive z-score (0,34) ... I have the std_deviations also.

**How do I calculate the probability of each of these groups, for the value to be below 75?**

1. For group 1: I have a z-score of -1,47; at 95% confidence interval is: 0,0606 => Thus a 6% chance of the value being below 75.
2. Now for group 2, my z-score is positive (0,34). This is where my brain gets all messed up ... How do I find the probability for this group 2, when my z-score is 0,34?  I am getting confused about where to apply the (1-X)?

Comment: I'm not sure which probability you are trying to calculate. Can you write it explicitly, by defining the random variables?

Comment: Basically, I am trying to find the probability of a data point being below 75.  For one of my means, I have a z-score as negative.  For another mean, I have a z-score as positive.  I'm simply trying to know, for the negative z-score, is this probability the critical value in the chart?  And for the positive z-score, do I also just look at the critical value in the chart?  Only difference being that I'm looking at the positive z-chart instead of negative z-chart?

Comment: I can't make sense neither your calculations nor the probability you ask for, even for the first one. For the first group, you have a mean (76.06) and a deviation, say $\sigma_1$. Are you asking for the probability of a chosen individual $X$ from the first group to be less than 75? If that's the case, are you trying to find the following: $$P(X<75)=P(Z<\frac{75-76.06}{\sigma_1})$$ and, is the z-value you're referring to (i.e. $-1.47$ is obtained via $\frac{75-76.06}{\sigma_1}$? If yes, how did you connect 95% CI and found 0.0606?

Comment: My standard deviation for the first group is 0,72.  So my z-score is -1.47.  Looking at a z-chart, the critical value is then: 0,0606 (I rounded up and chose -1.5 for my z).